# Generate numbers between two dates in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

i want generate series of number on two given dates in postgresql.
ex.
generate series number of two dates like '2005-04-01' and '2006-03-31' it is like financial dates

for '2005-04-01' and '2006-03-31'

```
1
2
3
4
.
.
100
```

for '2006-04-01' and '2007-03-31'

```
1
2
3
.
.
.
100
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it:

```
select t.num
from generate_series(1, date '2006-03-31' - date '2005-04-01') as t(num);
```

Or if it's always exactly 100 days:

```
select date '2005-04-01' + t.num
from generate_series(1, 100) as t(num);
```

Comment: how to generate series numbers from using table two dates i.e. from_date and to_date and  number should be initialise on 1 April of every year. every start of the financial year number should be start with 1